# Problem with migrations with docker and symfony

Tags: docker, symfony

I'm getting error when trying to do the migrations from the symfony cli to the docker

It is my first time using both of these so it is most likely some rookie mistake but when I create a project with the symfony CLI I'm trying to make a simple CRUD with the commands themselves. So I create a webapp, it doesn't flag anything, I create a entity and make the crud out of it, still without any flags, do docker-compose up -d, and here a lot of information pops on the screen so I'm not sure if everything went allright but it seems so, now when i run make:migration 3 instances of errors driver not found appear.
I just followed the cli instalation guide on symfony main page, and the docker i just downloaded the exe, ran it and made an account, could this be some config error on any of those that I have to fix first?
Sorry for the english it's not my first language

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing a lot of information in your question, but "driver not found" seems like you havent installed/enabled the correct database php extension.

If you are using the official php docker images, you can use the `docker-php-ext-install [package]`.  In some cases it requires you to install additional packages.

I think you are using mysql, so installing mysql php packages should be as simple as adding `RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql` to you `Dockerfile`.

FYI, this is just a quick answer, it doesn't cover any additional packages in case the installation fails. And doesn't cover best practices on how to setup your Dockerfile.